# jQuery slide on off multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I wanted a on off slidertype button in jQuery. After going through I got this [plugin](http://rawnet.github.io/jquery-switch/). Here is the [fiddle](http://rawnet.github.io/jquery-switch/) link for the plugin. This one is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/D3u9d/1/) link for this plugin. Now you can see in my fiddle link I have two two options like with and height settings and I want to store those values to my database so that when I will refresh the page it will be remain unchanged.
So to make that I will take the button values when some changes have been done. But here in the demo you can see it is only adding class named as on and off.It is okay to work with it when only one button(setting) is there. But how to work with multiple settings(buttons) will be there? So any help and suggestions will be really apprecable. Thanks

My markup code is like this

```
Width Settings:
<select class="test">
  <option value="1">On</option>
  <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
<br/>

Height Settings:
<select class="test1">
  <option value="1">On</option>
  <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
```

and jQuery code is like this

```
$(function() {
    $('select').switchify();
    $('select').data('switch').bind('slide', function(e, type) {
    $('ul').append('<li>Switching ' + type); 
    });
    jQuery('.ui-switch-middle').live('click',function(){
      if(!jQuery('.ui-switch').hasClass('on')) {
      console.log('on');
    }
    else {
      console.log('off');
    }
    })

  });
```

Comment: Is this what do you want http://jsfiddle.net/sX7Xu/ ?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward yes upto some level but how do I know which button has been clicked in case of I have 10 buttons?
If I am doing `console.log(this)` it is showing 
`<div class="ui-switch on" tabindex="0">` for every button. So how can I know the button value and insert them to the database?

Comment: By inspecting the plugin code I see that __$(this).data('select')__ store the reference to the original select element http://jsfiddle.net/sX7Xu/1/. If it's what you are looking for I post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Added IDs to the select's as follows:

```
Width Settings:
<select id='widthSettings' class="test">
    <option value="1">On</option>
    <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
<br/>Height Settings:
<select id='heightSettings' class="test1">
    <option value="1">On</option>
    <option value="0">Off</option>
</select>
<ul></ul>
```

And the javascript changes:

```
$(function () {
$('select').each(function () {
    $(this).switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function (e, type) {
        console.log(type)
        console.log($(this).data('select'))
        $('ul').append('<li>Switching ' + $(this).data('select').prop('id') + " " + type);
    });
})
});
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sX7Xu/2/) for working example